# How set owner of file cms.war for ftpuser and owner of cms folder for tomcat user?

Tags: permissions, tomcat, java, jsp

I'm using Tomcat Server. I would like the owner of the file `cms.war` to be the `ftp` user the `tomcat` user to be the owner of the `cms/` folder.

When I uploaded `cms.war` it was automatically deployed in `cms/` folder and when I deleted `cms.war` the `cms/` folder was deleted.

Comment: Isn't this expected behavior for auto-deploy?

Comment: Where is the question?

Answer (score 0):

The `chown` command can help you reassign the ownership of a file or folder. With Tomcat and autodeployment, the WAR file must be readable by the Tomcat user so that it can read and unpack it for deployment.

To change the owner of cms.war:

```
chown ftp cms.war
```

Note: This command is likely to require root privileges/sudo

To ensure that cms.war is readable by Tomcat:

```
chmod 744 cms.war
```

Note: This gives read, write, and execute privileges to the owner, and read privileges only to the group and others.

As for the Tomcat removing the the deployed cms/ folder when the WAR is deleted, that seems entirely reasonable behaviour for the autodeploy feature, as it allows you to easily add and remove web apps:

- When you add the WAR, Tomcat reads it and deploys it to a directory of the same name
- When you remove the WAR, Tomcat undeploys it by deleting the directory

What exactly is the problem with that?

Comment: The real problem is: i used cpanel+tomcat . i extracted war file next upload on server .

the owner folder is ftpuser . when the program want write to file , this error Occured:
can not permission to write file .

the permission of folder is 777 . tomcat user is member of that folder group . but tomcat can not write to file ???? . please help me!!